# Button not responding in fragment

Tags: android

I have created this application with 3 tabs, tabs are working fine but the button applied to tab1 is not responding on clicks. Tried everyway, not able to find any error. Is there anything wrong in my code?

Tab1.java

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    int click = 0;
    View view;
    Button button;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
         view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
        button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Button is clicked","Tab1");
                if(click == 0){

                MainActivity.swipe = 1;
                click = 1;
                }

                else if(click == 1){
                    MainActivity.swipe = 0;
                    click = 0;
                }
            }
        });

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1,container,false);

    }
}
```

And here is the XML file

```
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Tab1"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Comment: and u don't see the log phrase in logs?

Comment: No, not even once.

Comment: how do u show fragments, add code

Comment: Are you sure the button is in layout.tab1?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do `return view;` instead of `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1,container,false);`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now the button is responding. Cheers!